# Why does Thor feature the no_tasks method?

Tags: ruby, thor

Or, to be more specific: Can't I just use private methods instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand Thor it features ways to mark methods as [no tasks](http://textmate.rubyforge.org/thor/Thor/Base/ClassMethods.html#M000044) because the concept of a method being a task is different from the concept of a method's [visibility](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html#S4). They need to be differentiated because they do different jobs.

Every method (independently of its visibility) of a subclass to the class `Thor` is considered a task unless it is explicitly marked as no task. By controlling the visibility of a task you control access to that task, e.g. if you make a task private it cannot be called by subclasses or directly by a user. Access control is different from whether something is a task or not. Methods that are not tasks cannot be called directly by Thor and they cannot have [options](https://github.com/wycats/thor/wiki/Method-Options).

Here is an example to illustrate. In the following `SuperClass` inherits the task `baseTask` and the method `this_is_not_a_task` from `BaseClass`. Note that if the task `baseTask` is marked as private it will not be inherited by `SuperClass` but `this_is_not_a_task` will still be inherited.

```
require 'thor'

class BaseClass < Thor
  method_options :force => :boolean, :alias => :string

  desc 'baseTask', 'Base task'
  def baseTask
    puts this_is_not_a_task("base")
  end

  no_tasks do
    def this_is_not_a_task(s)
      s.upcase
    end
  end

  # private :baseTask
end

class SuperClass < BaseClass
  desc 'superTask', 'Super task'
  def superTask
    puts this_is_not_a_task("super")
  end
end

SuperClass.start(ARGV)
```

Comment: I really like your distinction of "a method being a task is different from the concept of a method's visibility"